# Primefaces Placeholder and Watermark causing problems for Autocomplete Panel at IE11 from version 5.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

I'm facing a weird issue with the `p:autoComplete`'s suggestion panel (`ui-autocomplete-panel`) when combined with following combinations of attributes:

- `scrollHeight` and `placeholder`
- `scrollHeight` and `p:watermark`

here is the code:

```
<p:autoComplete value="#{bean.text}" completeMethod="#{bean.complete}" 
                scrollHeight="200" placeholder="Enter Here..."/>
```

OR

```
<p:autoComplete id="textAuto" value="#{bean.text}" 
                completeMethod="#{bean.complete}" scrollHeight="200" />
<p:watermark for="textAuto" value="Enter Here..." />
```

Issue is:
Autocomplete suggestion Panel will disappear if click on scroll bar to scroll down when you clear the entire search text from search input field.

Its hard to explain the issue in words please see the following youtube video:

[https://youtu.be/O2mzX19MJh](https://youtu.be/ivBNuDc9_Xo)

The scenario is:

- Type a search text [Example: Hello].
- Option panel shows up with suggestions, select one.
- Remove the selected test completely from text box, by pressing backspace.
- Now click on dropdown button or search for a text by typing.
- Next time the options panel shows up. It will disappear when user click on scroll bar.

I have raised this issue in Primefaces issue tracker as well but there ain't no response to the issue yet, issue number is [1260](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1260).

Please note that this issue occurs only in Primefaces version 5.2 and above. Since release of version 5.2 they have made changes to `p:autocomplete` component by adding few more attributes, here is the release notes: http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3491

Does any one faced this same issue and found any workaround for this either from Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Impossible to stay focussed in the video. To much movement...

Comment: Sorry, I will re-upload a proper video in another 10 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this issue on PF 5.1.5 using the placeholder attribute with IE 11.

Try adding:

```
onfocus="this.placeholder = ''"
```

to your autocomplete component.  This fixes the issue.  The only downside is the watermark will not display until the component is refreshed but not a big deal in my opinion.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thank you for posting your answer.  I'm using PF 5.2 and facing the same issue in IE11, even with your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<p:autoComplete id="autoId"
 completeMethod="#{bean.complete}" value="#{bean.someVar}" var="ve" itemLabel="#{ve.title}" itemValue="#{ve}" 
 queryDelay="1200">
</p:autoComplete>
<p:watermark forElement="#autoId_input" value="This is watermark text" />
```